# Connecting to two ISP in local network using two different network

Tags: networking, route, network-interface, interface

We have two ISP 1. BSNL (INDIA), 2. Airtel (INDIA). we getting Bsnl internet through D-Link DSL 2750U modem which holds the IP 192.168.1.1, Airtel internet modem with 192.168.2.1 IP address, Here it's both are from different network. Mostly Bsnl internet not being stable annoying service provider. When ever BSNL internet unstable i want to get use the airtel without changing any configuration are manually routing every time. We have mostly all client machines in Linux (Ubuntu), Centos.

This is the interface configuration now i'am using in my Ubuntu desktop, Here i have bridged my network to use virtual machines. Don't confuse of this bridging.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.25
        network 192.168.1.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
        post up route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.1
```

Just i have tried to route from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.2.0 using route add in interface, But still there is no ping reply from 192.168.2.1. Did i want to add one more interface config for 192.168.2.0 using alias ? Any help will be mostly appreciated.

All i need to know how can i configure now while we have two internet connections, with 2 different modem with two different network range one is 192.168.1.1 IP range and other with 192.168.2.1 But my desktop and all client machines ip range was 192.168.1.0 series, My need here is when ever my internet which in 192.168.1.1 goes down i have to get the internet from 192.168.2.1 modem.

Comment: Using Bridge for my Virtual machines

Comment: Then did i have to avoid bridge ? How can i get connect with different network ISP

Comment: I don't know how to explain than above, I have tried everything what i know. After that only i came here to get help from you peoples. I have said clearly what i need to achieve. And i have mentioned what i have tried yet now.

Comment: I have clearly said that we have two internet connections, 2 different modem with two different network range one is 192.168.1.1 IP range and other with 192.168.2.1 But my desktop and all client machines ip range was 192.168.1.0 series, My need here is when ever my internet which in 192.168.1.1 goes down i have to get the internet from 192.168.2.1 modem. Hope you got now.

Comment: Deleted my previous comments in favor of a summarizing one. I asked the OP to improve the question in a number of ways and tried to help him in the chat. He has difficulties describing his actual set up. He's clearly using two routers to connect to two different ISPs. Those two routers are connected to one physical network with two different network prefixes and he's connecting a number of physical clients, some of which also host virtuals. He struggles getting an automatic fail over for all those machines without having a central router to perform the job.